# Unique identity for every Android device, Both gsm and non-gsm

Tags: android, activation, imei

I'm working on an android app project which needs activation for each device that runs this app.
On Windows PC I know some solutions like using HDD's serial number as unique identifier for activation process.

But I need a way to be used in Android devices that does not support SIM card, so those devices does not have IMEI serial.

Better to say I need a unique factor on all Android devices, both support and does not support SIM card.

Regards
Ata

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000103

Comment: I really wanna know the reason of down vote !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with this code also

import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);

this will remain unchanged util device get wiped off which is a rare Case...

Comment: Good answer, clean and simple

Answer (score 0):

you can use device id as unique identifier for activation. if the device has an imei you can use it or you can use build serial, the below code will help you

```
   /**
 * Fetch the device IMEI number.
 *
 * @param context Calling context
 * @return IMEI number as string.
 */
public static String getDeviceImei(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
}

/**
 * To get the device Id either in terms of IMEI number (For GSM phones) or Build.SERIAL for
 * non-GSM phones/tablets.
 *
 * @param context Calling context
 * @return Device Id.
 */
public static String getDeviceId(Context context) {
    String deviceId = getDeviceImei(context);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(deviceId)) {
        deviceId = Build.SERIAL;
    }
    return deviceId;
}
```